# Guess the word from the hints

Tags: riddle, word

> You can find me on a table
>   Believe me, I am capable
>   When I soar, beings pour
>   You think I'm dizzy
>   But I'm actually busy
>   I'm very near hence I don't support anyone dear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are

> Mercury

You can find me on a table

> It as an element on the table of elements (Hg)

Believe me, I am capable

> Mercury has many uses- thermometers, barometers, sphygmomonometers, various alloys

When I soar, beings pour

> Mercury is used in thermometers- when the temperature increases the mercury rises and people sweat (pour)

You think I'm dizzy

> Mercury poisoning can result in dizziness

But I'm actually busy

> Mercury is used in blood pressure readings- it's busy being useful?
>  or- Mercury (the winged messenger) is busy?

I'm very near hence I don't support anyone dear

> Mercury is the closest planet to the sun- due to its proximity, it is uninhabitable

I'm unsure of some parts- help welcome!

Comment: Good start, but I think the very title of this puzzle is "I may refer to multiple things, but I am one" so you probably shouldn't be referring to both at different points in the answer.

Comment: @leigero the one-word answer has different meanings, that's the "multiple" part

Comment: Dizzy because it rotates around it's axis. Nice work.

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> Degrees

You can find me on a table

> there are 4 90 degree corners on a table.

Believe me, I am capable

> You have a degree, so you're very capable/educated/qualified

When I soar, beings pour

> When the degrees rise (temperature) people sweat/pour

You think I'm dizzy

> 360 degrees spinning?

But I'm actually busy

> Someone with a degree is constantly working

I'm very near hence I don't support anyone dear

> 1 degree of separation?

Answer (score 3):

It is a

> Lazy Susan.

You can find me on a table

> Yep.

Believe me, I am capable

> A lazy Susan isn't actually very lazy, thus capable?

When I soar, beings pour

> Try spinning one really fast when there is are liquids on it, see what happens!

You think I'm dizzy

> from all that spinning around...

But I'm actually busy

> Spinning is working for one of those.

I'm very near hence I don't support anyone dear

> The lazy Susan is in the centre of a round table and thus equally near to every one at the table.

Comment: By beings I meant living beings :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Glass

You can find me on a table

> Yes, you can.

Believe me, I am capable

> Google glass

When I soar, beings pour

> glass actually used for pouring

You think I'm dizzy

> When you have a myotopia, you may think it all spins around

But I'm actually busy

> Traffic seems too busy through blur glasses

I'm very near hence I don't support anyone dear

> It is related with spectacles

Comment: Nice thinking. I like the Google Glass part.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Salt

You can find me on a table

> in salt shakers

Believe me, I am capable

> being worth your salt

When I soar, beings pour

> When Salt levels are high, people sweat

You think I'm dizzy

> Dizziness spells calls by too much salt in diet

But I'm actually busy

> Serves a lot of functions

I'm very near hence I don't support anyone dear

> exists everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> a cat?

You can find me on a table

> cats sit on the table

Believe me, I am capable

> cats are quite capable at a lot of things, though they lounge around

When I soar, beings pour

> soar to heaven? people cry?

You think I'm dizzy

> alternate definition for dizzy (bewildered; confused.) cats stare off into space

But I'm actually busy

> they are thinking! brains are busy

I'm very near hence I don't support anyone dear

> although always around, cats don't seem to care about anything other than themselves

Comment: Love this answer but it's nowhere close to what I have in mind :)